# Highcharts: Nothing change happens whatever I setting formatter:function() or set tooltip{enabled:false}

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

```js
        series: [
     
        {          
         tooltip:{
             enabled:true,
             formatter:function(){
            var $index=this.point.index;
         return $steps_array[$index]+'steps'+'<br>'+'rank: top'+$top_school_persent[$index]+'%';
             }
            }],
            name: 'steps',
            type:'spline',
            data: $steps_array
        },
```

When I use above code,the page like this:
[image]
I find when I change the formatter function, the picture didn't change.So I set the tooltip like this:

```js
series:[
  tooltip:{
  enabled:false},
  name:'steps',
  type:'spline',
  data:$steps_array
  
  ]
```

But there is no change.The tooltip still exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tooltip.enabled](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.enabled) and [tooltip.formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter) are global properties - they do not apply for a specific series.

If you want to have a disabled tooltip for a specific series, you can disable mouse events - but it also disable click events for the series.

```
series: [{
            enableMouseTracking: false,
            data: ...
        }, {
            data: ...
        }]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g1qj78d3/1/

Or create a correct formatter callback which checks for a specific series

```
tooltip: {
      formatter: function () {
        return this.series.name === 's1' ? false : 'custom tooltip';
      }
    },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g1qj78d3/2/

Comment: Thanks. I have used the second method to deal with it.